# Hyperlink inside webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, webview

I made a webview in android and its working very fine, but what i want is that the user can navigate the website in the webview but when the user click the hyperlink in the webview i want it to open the link in chrome.. Here is my webview code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView wb;
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        wb.loadUrl("https://example.com");
    }
}
```

A link on my website is as follows, but i dont want this link to open inside my webview i want it to open on chrome

```
<a href="https://google.com" class="button" >Google</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // check url
    if(url.contains("google.com")) {
        // below line will open default app with url
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        // return true when url was handled somehow and doesn't need to be loaded
        return true;
    }
    return false; // not handled manually urls, open them in WebView
}
```

`startActivity` belongs to `Context` (`Acticity` extends it) and may be used straight as your `HelloWebViewClient` is placed inside, but if it would not be then you may use `WebView`s `Context`

```
view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
```